# Jquery Ajax isn't working properly with Laravel Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, pagination

I am trying to load records from database table using ajax and laravel pagination

This is my user interface 
[image]

Code to display pagination buttons

```
<div class="pull-right" id="inboxcount">

    <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-url=" " id="inbox_prev_page_url"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-url=" " id="inbox_next_page_url"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On page load I am fetching data from table using ajax , currently I kept pagination for 2 records so that it is easy to understand.

Ajax code to load the records first time when page is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
      $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/sanimailer/public/get-inbox/2",
          dataType: "json",
          type:"get",
          async: true,
          success: function(data) 
          {
            if(data!='NULL')
            {
              console.log(data);

              $("[id=inboxcount]").prepend(data['from'] + ' - ' + data['to'] + ' / ' + data['total']);
              $("[id=inbox_prev_page_url]").attr("data-url",data['prev_page_url']);
              $("[id=inbox_next_page_url]").attr("data-url",data['next_page_url']);

              for (var i=0; i<data['data'].length; i++) 
              {
                  var fromName = data['data'][i].fromName;
                  var fromAddress = data['data'][i].fromAddress;
                  var subject = (data['data'][i].subject).substr(0,50); 
                  var date = data['data'][i].date;


                  var row = $('<tr><td><input type=checkbox></td><td class=mailbox-star><a href=#><i class=fa fa-star text-yellow></i></a></td><td class=mailbox-name><a href=# title='+ fromAddress + '>' + fromName + '</a></td><td class=mailbox-subject>' + subject + '</td><td class=mailbox-attachment><i class=fa fa-paperclip></i></td><td class=mailbox-date>' + date + '</td></tr>');

                  $("#inboxtable").append(row);
              }
            }

          }});

});
```

After loading results are shown in above image.
Here you can see i have updated **data-url** attribute for both the buttons

Now if i click on next button next data is loaded ,here is ajax code for next button click event

```
$("[id=inbox_next_page_url]").click(function(){

        var url=$("[id=inbox_next_page_url]").data("url");

        $.ajax({
          url:url,
          dataType: "json",
          type:"get",
          async: true,
          success: function(data) 
          {
            if(data!='NULL')
            {

              console.log(data);
              // $("#inboxtable").empty();
              $("[id=inbox_prev_page_url]").attr("data-url","");
              $("[id=inbox_next_page_url]").attr("data-url","");


              $("[id=inboxcount]").prepend(data['from'] + ' - ' + data['to'] + ' / ' + data['total']);
              $("[id=inbox_prev_page_url]").attr("data-url",data['prev_page_url']);
              $("[id=inbox_next_page_url]").attr("data-url",data['next_page_url']);

              alert($("[id=inbox_next_page_url]").attr("data-url"));

              for (var i=0; i<data['data'].length; i++) 
              {
                  var fromName = data['data'][i].fromName;
                  var fromAddress = data['data'][i].fromAddress;
                  var subject = (data['data'][i].subject).substr(0,50); 
                  var date = data['data'][i].date;


                  var row = $('<tr><td><input type=checkbox></td><td class=mailbox-star><a href=#><i class=fa fa-star text-yellow></i></a></td><td class=mailbox-name><a href=# title='+ fromAddress + '>' + fromName + '</a></td><td class=mailbox-subject>' + subject + '</td><td class=mailbox-attachment><i class=fa fa-paperclip></i></td><td class=mailbox-date>' + date + '</td></tr>');


                  $("#inboxtable").append(row);
              }
            }

          }});
      });
```

Here you see , I am updating **data-url** attribute of prev and next button.
When I inspect code I see data-url is updated for next button, but when I click on next the current **data-url** it shows always, actually it should show updated value in **data-url** but it shows same data ,and i am not able to load further records becasue of this.

Console Data

[image]

check this [image]

Not sure why the pagination is not proceeding further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the pagination isn't progressing is because jQuery keeps fetching its internally cached version of the url data attribute when you use `.data('url')` on your next button click. To always fetch the current attribute fresh from the DOM, use `.attr('data-url')`.

So change your line:

`var url = $("[id=inbox_next_page_url]").data("url");`

to

`var url=$("[id=inbox_next_page_url]").attr("data-url");`

and your code will work.

From the `.data()` [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery).

And here's [a related post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-data-caching-of-data-attributes) on the jQuery forums.